# How to get stream id for node.js streams?

Tags: node.js, spdy

For pushed streams, I tried following code

```
agent.on('push', function(stream) {
  console.log('stream id is %s',stream.streamID);
}
```

but cannot get the stream ID.

I also looked at the whole stream object and can see in _spdyState, there is a field for stream id, but how can I extract this information?